# Tabs UI using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

**http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation** the tabs manipulation does a click to add a tab. but i need a little tweak in there. after i click the add tab i.e., clicking add tab creates a tab2..but the screen doesn't takes the view to the second tab. It remains in the first tab but add the second tab(which is not active after click)

I need **tab2** to be active after clicking the add button...this process continues for all the adding tabs.

I need a example or a way..coz it's a showstopper for my current project

Answer (score 0):

There’s a link of the bottom of that page, *“Want to learn more about the tabs widget? Check out the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/).”*

And to get from there to http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active should not be an impossible task for a developer, don’t you think …?

Comment: see am a newbie to jquery UI and i don't know a API Documentation down there...Anyway Thanks for the reply... And i don't think it as impossible one when i put the query...